# How to hide text in navbar elements on different screen size Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

How do I hide elements of a navbar in bootstrap inline rather than creating a new element for each screen size. I tried using a span but that just causes the line to wrap.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Alliteration App<span class="d-none d-sm-block">lication</span>s</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="definition.html">Definition</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="part-of-speech.html">By Parts of Speech</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" active>
        <a class="nav-link" href="sentence.html">Sentence Supplier <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="synonym.html">Synonym Seeker</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The example below is the only solution I have found to hide and show based on screen size. But I do not like the code it looks a little messy

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand d-block d-sm-none" href="index.html">Alliteration Apps</a>
  <a class="navbar-brand d-none d-sm-block float-left" href="index.html">Alliteration Applications</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="definition.html">Definition</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="part-of-speech.html">By Parts of Speech</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" active>
        <a class="nav-link" href="sentence.html">Sentence Supplier <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="synonym.html">Synonym Seeker</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your first solution, reason the line's wrapped is because you're using `d-sm-block`, I believe `d-sm-inline` does the job.